# Django cannot makemessages for djangojs

Tags: django

Currently I have this problem when trying to translate javascript files for Django. I have the `url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),` in urls.py and get that one in the template. This does not seem to be the issue to translating, when I run the `django-admin.py makemessages` command, it will throw some errors and I do not know why.

```
   $ django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l nl_NL --keep-pot
    CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
    /Users/../../src/locale/djangojs.pot:120: context separator <EOT> within string
    /Users/../../src/locale/djangojs.pot:121: context separator <EOT> within string
    msguniq: found 2 fatal errors
```

This is what I find in the `djangojs.pot` file

```
#: static/jsi18n/djangojs.js:38 static/jsi18n/djangojs.js:46
#: static/jsi18n/nl/djangojs.js:84 static/jsi18n/nl/djangojs.js:92
msgid " "
msgid_plural ""
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""
```

When I delete these lines with empty string and run the command again, it will simply add them again after the command ran. Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: It seems to mee that the files mentioned in the .pot have identical msgid strings (a space). Why are these js files scanned for translations at all? It seems that the /nl/djangojs.js is  dedicated to the Dutch translation. Why would it contain translation strings?

Comment: I did delete the other one, so it has only this one `#: static/jsi18n/nl/djangojs.js:84 static/jsi18n/nl/djangojs.js:92`. It still errors, so it is not that it has identical strings. It goes wrong here (this is in djangojs.js:84): `var value = django.gettext(context + '\x04' + msgid);`. Seems like it cannot handle the \x04 or something @allcaps

Answer (score 3):

> Error Description

What happens here that it has created **djangojs.js** files like **static/js/i18n/nl_NL/djangojs.js** for all of your supported languages and in each language file it has **'\x04'** strings inside these files

So when you run this command

```
django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l nl_NL
```

It considers these ** djangojs.js** files as a valid source code which is used to fetch strings of these for i18n, so it consider these **'\x04'** string and create a msgid for it in **.po** files and create this entry in **.pot** file

```
msgid "^D"
msgstr ""
```

**^D** is an `<EOT>` character and that's what django says in the following error

```
djangojs.pot:120: context separator <EOT> within string
```

So where ever this error comes to your command exits here without completion. After fixing it you need to re-run this command to execute it completely.

> Solution

You need to do these following things

1. No need to change any of your **djangojs.js** files
2. don't consider **djangojs.js** files for i18n

**So in order to fix this you need to ignore these files and don't consider these files for i18n (internationalization) by adding `--ignore` keyword in makemessages command like below**

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=$bn --domain=djangojs --ignore=static/js/i18n/*
```

It will fix your error. :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the `\x04` strings from the `djangojs.js` file, and leave an empty string there. This is not a nice fix, but it seems to work for me. I read some about this issue in this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17008. It seems like it cannot escape this in the javascript file.

```
./static/jsi18n/djangojs.js:90: warning: Empty msgid.  It is reserved by GNU gettext:
                                         gettext("") returns the header entry with
                                         meta information, not the empty string.
```

This is the warning I get, but then again this seems to fix the translation problem for now.